# Importing from a package that uses Django as ORM gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: package, django-orm

Versions:

- Django 2.0.3
- Python3.6.3

I have a package (mypkg) that uses django as ORM.

I want to use that package in a client script (client/myclient/main.py).

I was able to use Django ORM directly inside a client app - the problem is when I want to use it inside a package that is used by multiple client apps.

The package code is as follows:

```
# ./mypkg_wrapper/mypkg/mypkg/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'myapp',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

SECRET_KEY = '...'

# mypkg/myapp/models.py

from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# mypkg_wrapper/setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='A django ORM package.',
    install_requires=['django', 'pytz']
)
```

I ran makemigrations, migrate to set up the database.

I ran `python setup.py sdist`, which created `mypkg_wrapper/dist/mypkg-0.0.1.tar.gz`

Client code:

```
# myclient/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'mypkg.myapp',
]

SECRET_KEY = '...'

# myclient/main.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
    import sys
    import django

    sys.path.append(join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), '..'))
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
    django.setup()

    import mypkg.myapp
```

In the client venv, I ran `pip install ../mypkg_wrapper/mypkg-0.0.1.tar.gz`, which seems to install the mypkg package successfully.

I then tried to run `python myclient/main.py` and I got the following error while trying to import mypkg.myapp.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'`

The package mypkg is in the client's venv:

```
$ pip list
Django (2.0.3)
mypkg (0.0.1)
pip (9.0.1)
pytz (2018.3)
setuptools (28.8.0)
```

I saw similar questions here, but none of the answers addressed this issue.

I tried/considered several things:

1. `import mypkg` in `main.py` - same error
2. `mypkg` instead of `mypkg.myapp` in client `INSTALLED_APPS` - same error
3. Not sure if I need to create a database in each client? How would the database work across multiple clients of the package?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal git repo? It would be faster to test and fix

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your app appears inside the venv installed packages folder?
It should be something like

```
.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

If it is there check the files to see if there's something strange.
If it isn't there then the package wasn't installed.

EDIT: Surely your Python folder might be 3.6